# Angular orderBy with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

How to use Angular orderBy method with multidimensional array?

```
$scope.multidimensionalArray = [[]];
...
$scope.multidimensionalArray = orderBy($scope.multidimensionalArray, ???, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement you own filter as in :

```
.filter('myFilter', function(arr) {
  return sortedArr;
});
```

In controller

```
$filter('myFilter')(arr);
```

And in template

```
<div ng-repeat="arr|myFilter">
```